# Drupal - fetch body text of a node via URL?

Tags: php, drupal, caching

I'm trying to create a function to retrieve and display just the Body field of a Drupal node, based on a given URL.

Currently, I've extended the functionality of the standard Drupal RSS to do a detection method.  This will happen if you enter the following url:
http://mysite.com/rss.xml/**page=54**

That last part is critical - it tells what node ID to load from.  As far as code goes, I've modified the node_feed() function in /modules/node/node.module to do the following:

```
if (stristr($nids, 'page=') !== FALSE) {
 $nid = substr($nids, stripos($nids, 'page=') + 5);
 $result = NULL;

 if ((string)(int)$nid === $nid) {
  $result = db_result(db_query("SELECT `nid` FROM {node} WHERE `nid` = %s AND `type` =  'flashnode'", $nid));
 }

 if ($result) {
   $item = node_load($result);
   print($item->body);
 }
 exit;
}
```

While this **works**, we're worried about it for two reasons:

1) Do the results cache?  This is a very heavy-load page that will be called a lot.

2) Is there an **"official"** way to do this?  One that uses modules with caching, instead of a semi-hacky workaround?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.
-Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely not be hacking apart the RSS feed in order to create a URL that returns a node's body. You should create a very simple custom module: http://drupal.org/developing/modules

The Drupal module system is lets you set up a url so that something like `/fetch_body/1234` calls the fetch_body() function with $nid=1234 as the parameter. As for caching, you have a lot of options in your custom module. The most obvious would be to use cache_get() and cache_set() to do simple caching on your own based on the node ID.

What version of Drupal are you using? I would highly recommend the book Pro Drupal Development, just make sure to get the edition that matches your drupal version.

Comment: Hey, I'm using Drupal 6.  I went with your suggestion - building a custom module - and it works very nicely!  It doesn't use fetch body, instead it grabs $_GET and inspects it for incoming variables, and acts accordingly.  Thank you very much.

Comment: That works, but Drupal actually has some additional features deal with parsing URLs and $_GET for you.